# Azure Active directory authentication and Xamarin app

Tags: xamarin, azure-active-directory

I am new to Xamarin and Azure AD.

Currently I am working on one of the Xamarin cross platform mobile App which use Azure Active directory for user authentication.

So the issue is when I open my app instead of showing me the App login screen it redirects me to Microsoft login screen. I want my users to see my App login screen and use that for sign in instead of Microsoft login screen. Is there any way I can do that?

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Can you show some code of how you're accessing the Azure AD? Thanks

Comment: Azure AD is federated authentication. There is a way to send credentials without the redirect, but it is not recommended because of some corner cases like expired passwords. You *need* to redirect the users to the Azure AD sign in page.

Comment: Thanks  woelliJ and juunas for the reply. Sorry woelliJ I am not allowed to share the code here.

Comment: i just came across this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/

basically what you want is "passwort grant with azure AD" (passwort grant type = username and login entries defined within the app) maybe you can find more on it online. in general it's about OAuth spec. if you can modify the server code you might be able to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we integrate Azure AD with the application, it actual use the [OAuth 2.0 l](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)/[OpenId Connect](http://openid.net/connect/) protoco.
And based on the protocol, when the users need to enter the credential, it needs to redirect to the authorization server(Azure AD) like below.

[image]

If the users enter the credentials of Azure AD on a page which is not belongs Microsoft, it sounds like Phishing site and it will lead the security issues.

If you want to add company branding to your sign-in page, you can refer the article below:

[Add company branding to your sign-in and Access Panel pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-add-company-branding)